# Neural Network loss function value = NaN

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, categorical-data, loss-function

For an assignment, I am trying to train a Neural Network to predict the Crime Category in a public dataset from my city:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVyaV.png)

After finiding the Neural Network architechture that works the best, I started trying different Loss Functions and Optimizers.

Using a mean squared error loss function I never got more than 20% accuracy

With a 'kullback_leibler_divergence' I couldn't get more than 70% accuracy

Then I tried using "SparseCategoricalCrossentropy" and while the accuracy is perfect now, I get the value of the loss funcion as nan (And I don't know if that's wrong, but it seems wrong).

This is how the code looks:

```
##### Neural Network Architecture:
my_model = tf.keras.Sequential ([    
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,input_shape = (9,)),         
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4,activation = "Softmax")
])

##### LOSS & OPTIMIZERS
loss_f = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy (from_logits=True)
#opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.025, momentum=0.8)
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
my_model.compile(loss=loss_f, optimizer=opt, metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
my_model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size= 252, validation_data=(x_dev, y_dev), epochs = 25)
```

And this is the output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p8UP.png)

I have tried using different optimizers like momentum, changing learn rate, and even changing the whole Network architecture and it is always the same, 100% accuracy by the second epoch and a loss function = nan.

Comment: Try this once, just to see is the error somewhere in the data processing or the actual loss function: `my_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
`

Comment: Thank you so much! It turns out that at some point I decided to run the program without normalizing the numerical data to see what happened. I fixed that and it's now running correctly.

Comment: Good to know it worked out well for you!